# Port redirection from 80 to 8080 using iptables not working

Tags: http, tomcat, redirect, port, iptables

Good day, I had a Tomcat running on port 80 on a CentOS server with IP 10.33.46.68. When I tried to open "http://10.33.46.68" on my notebook I could see Tomcat welcome page. 
Then I changed Tomcat port to 8080 and redirected HTTP traffic on port 80 to port 8080 using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Now when I try to open "http://10.33.46.68" on my notebook I'm getting timeout.
But when I try to open "http://10.33.46.68" or "http://10.33.46.68:8080" directly on the server both URLs works fine. What am I missing please?

There is a Cisco firewall between the notebook and the server which allows communication on port 80 only. This is my iptables configuration file:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Oct 17 14:51:20 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1027:228609]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 17 14:51:20 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Oct 17 14:51:20 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:274]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:154]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 17 14:51:20 2012
```

Many thanks in advance. Vojtech

Comment: The redirection of iptables is configured on the server right ? (just to clarify).

Comment: Yes, on the CentOS server.

Comment: Can you `telnet 10.33.46.68 80` from the notebook ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `INPUT` chain in the `filter` table shouldn't be DROP. (well, at least not exclusively without accepting ports!)

At least accept port tcp/8080 to make it work.

The packet first traverses the mangle-, then the prerouting, and then the filter table. Your mangle table is empty, you redirect in prerouting, but when the packet enters INPUT/filter, it's getting droped.

A simple `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` should be sufficient.

Edit: Accepting localhost in the INPUT-chain of filter should be there too, just not to complicate the things. Although you should consider implementing rules which are a littel more sophisticated, something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT # don't you want ssh?
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Many thanks, adding "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT" before line "-A INPUT -j DROP" helped.